# Error with Firestore update in a Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I try to put a listener on Firebase that will replicate a value in the matching element in Firestore.

```
exports.synchronizeDelegates = functions.database.ref(`delegates/{userId}/activities`).onUpdate((event) => {
        const userKey = event.data.ref.parent.key

        console.log("User Key:" + userKey)

        return admin.database().ref(`delegates/${userKey}/email`).once('value', snapshot => {

            let email = snapshot.val()

            console.log("Exported Email:" + email)

            const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users')
            const firestoreRef = userRef.where('email', "==", email)

            firestoreRef.onSnapshot().update({ activities: event.data.toJSON() })

        }).then(email => {
            console.log("Firebase  Data successfully updated")
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
)
```

This function is able to retrieve and locate the elemnt needed to target the right document in firestore, but the `.update()`function still error `firestoreRef.update is not a function`
I try several ways to query but I still have this error.

How to properly query then update a document in this scenario?

Comment: Have you tried replacing that line with this: `firestoreRef.update({ activities: event.data.toJSON() })` ?

Comment: Yes, I try to chain the update() method just after the query and it return the same error.

Comment: Btw: I love that you're using Cloud Functions to synchronize Cloud Firestore to the Realtime Database.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this is irony @FrankvanPuffelen, but in my situation, the `activities` field in my RTDB is updated by a third party vendor who gets write access to my database through the API. As I move forward with Firestore for my client view, it is the fastest way I found to make this works, as I can't control the third-party development at this point. Next step will be obvious, to update the third party provider to write in Firestore

Comment: Wasn't ironic at all. Sorry if it came across as such. I've been meaning to write such RTDB-to-Firestore sync functions for some of my projects, but... too much other stuff keeps coming up. Good to see that at least someone is getting to it. :-)

Comment: My bad, I become paranoïd after "being bullied" on Stack :) Writing these script for transitioning is a bit tedious but will ensure a smooth transition!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [onSnapshot()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/Query#onSnapshot) method of [Query](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/Query) introduces a persistent listener that gets triggered every time there's a new QuerySnapshot available.  It keeps doing this until the listener is unsubscribed.  This behavior is definitely not what you want.  Also, there's no update() method on QuerySnapshot that your code is trying to call.

Instead, it looks like you want to use [get()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/Query#get) to fetch a list of documents that match your query, then update them all:

```
exports.synchronizeDelegates = functions.database.ref(`delegates/{userId}/activities`).onUpdate((event) => {
    const userId = event.params.userId
    console.log("User Key:" + userKey)

    return admin.database().ref(`delegates/${userId}/email`).once('value', snapshot => {

        let email = snapshot.val()

        console.log("Exported Email:" + email)

        const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users')
        const query = usersRef.where('email', "==", email)

        const promises = []
        query.get().then(snapshots => {
            snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
                promises.push(snapshot.ref.update(event.data.val()))
            })
            return Promise.all(promises)
        })
    }).then(email => {
        console.log("Firebase  Data successfully updated")
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Note that I rewrote some other things in your function that were not optimal.

In general, it's a good idea to stay familiar with the Cloud Firestore API docs to know what you can do.

Comment: Thank for your input @Doug the `event.params.userId`is also a great learning.